# Move focus on WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, focus

I have one application in WPF.

In which we have some button control. On the click of the button it opnes a popup control.

The problems is after clicking on button it does not move focus on opened pop up.

I want the solution using XAMLcode only.there is no CS file.

Thanks 
Harshil

Comment: how do you handle the click? Trigger or MVVM?

Comment: Please post a stripped down version of your existing code (XAML) that repros the problem.  Edit your question, and add that code.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in XAML only you will need classes which let you invoke methods since that is necessary to move the focus around, `Interactivity` from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1ae9a30-4928-411d-970b-e682ab179e17&displaylang=en) lets you do this to some degree but i did not get it to work with the [`Focus` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus.aspx). Possibly something like [this markup programming library](http://markupprogramming.codeplex.com/) would work; you could also implement some custom markup extension which does the invocation, but in general XAML-only is not trivial here.

...and it is somewhat pointless to do that in the first place. If you have imperative code like "open popup then focus it" then just use code behind, that's what it is for.